# Selection sort with strings in an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, selection-sort

I'm having problems with a selection sort of strings inside structs. All the values I enter do not change position after the sort. I think that I am missing something minor, but I haven't been able to find related help on the internet. `*p_customer_start` points to the beginning of the array. `p_outer` and `p_inner` are supposed to be doing the sorting. Does anyone know what is going wrong?

```
void sort_customers(int quantity, struct customer *p_customer_start)
{
struct customer *p_customer,
*p_outer,
*p_inner,
temp_customer;

printf("\nInside the sorting function.");

for(p_customer = p_customer_start; (p_customer-p_customer_start) < quantity; p_customer++)
{
    p_inner = p_customer;

    for(p_outer = p_customer + 1; p_outer <= quantity; p_outer++)
        if(strcmp(p_outer->customer_name, p_inner->customer_name) > 0)
            p_inner = p_outer;

    temp_customer = *p_customer;
    *p_customer = *p_inner;
    *p_inner = temp_customer;

    p_inner++;
}

 return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably this comparison

```
p_outer <= quantity
```

you might want to try this instead

```
p_outer <= (p_customer_start + (quantity-1))
```

**p_outer** will be pointing to some system memory location, and the address of the memory location is probably greater the the number of elements in the array you are sorting.

Comment: I tried to put what you said, and now I'm going out of the bounds of memory.

Comment: @Jesse -- try this test: p_outer <= (p_customer_start + (quantity-1))

Comment: I actually tinkered around a bit more and came up with this: (p_outer-p_inner) <= quantity. It seems to be working fine. But thanks for the interest in my question!